# Distinct list of Items after Query

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a table with two filters on it. Both filters are in the form of Dropdown widgets; when a user selects an item from the list of options in the Dropdowns, the table is filtered to include only records with that item. Each Dropdown filter is a Relation to the table's datasource.

Currently, each Dropdown's Options is just the full list of Items from that Dropdown's particular datasource. However, when the value of one Dropdown is changed by the user, I would like the other Dropdown's Options list to be populated only with

For example, I have a table of US and Canadian citizens and their home state/province. The first Dropdown filters the table by country, the second by state/province. If I select 'Canada' from the first Dropdown, then when I select an item for the second Dropdown, only Canadian provinces appear as options, and none of the US states would.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have three independent datasources:

- Countries
- States
- People

To filter items in States dropdown you can reload its datasource in onValueChange event of dropdown with Сountries. You can also simplify your life by binding `@datasources.States.query.filters.Country._equals` to Countries's dropdown value.

```js
// Countries dropdown onValueChange event handler
// newValue - new selected country
app.datasources.States.load();

// unfortunately App Maker doesn't allow to bind multiple things to
// one value, so we need explicitly set filter for People datasource
app.datasources.People.query.filters.Country._equals = newValue;
app.datasources.People.load();
```

Depending on your business needs, you maybe will want to force users first select country by disabling dropdown with states:

```js
// States dropdown `enabled` property binding
@datasources.States.query.filters.Country._equals !== null
```